# "ant -version" returns /usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Some specified jars were not found

Tags: linux, ant

When typing "$ ant -version" into a linux terminal window I receive 2 errors followed by the version # and when it was compiled.

The first error:
`/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Could not find xml-commons-apis Java extension for this JVM`

The second error:

`/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Some specified jars were not found`

Followed by

`Apache Ant version 1.6.5 compiled on January 6 2007`

I have $JAVA_HOME set to the jdk location and added to my path

What could be the cause of these errors?

Comment: What's your `ANT_HOME` set to?

Comment: at the moment it is not set to anything

Comment: also `which ant` returns `usr/bin/ant` but there is no ant directory in my usr/bin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may have missed part of an [installation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) step.

> Set environmental variables JAVA_HOME to your Java environment, ANT_HOME to the directory you uncompressed Ant to, and add ${ANT_HOME}/bin (Unix) or %ANT_HOME%/bin (Windows) to your PATH. See Setup for details.

A lot of JAR files used by Ant are stored in your `${ANT_HOME}/lib` directory, so Ant needs to know where this is.  Be sure to set the `ANT_HOME` environment variable and set `${ANT_HOME}/bin` in your path.

If there's a JAR file missing from your installation, you might just need to manually download it and install it in your `${ANT_HOME}/lib` directory.  There are a lot of tasks that don't work on a clean Ant installation and need the right JAR installed.

Comment: @user2497792 I have the same exact error what you had. Could you tell me if you had to install right JAR or just setting en variables fixed your problem?